# Cannot open disk file using assembler syscalls on aarch64 device

Tags: android, arm64, gnu-assembler, termux

I am a Hobby programmer here now trying to get into assembler for an android phone. I cannot open a disk file.
I would dearly like to get past this hurdle if anybody with a knowledge of gnu assemblers for aarch64 could help me out.

I am using the Termux application, which is a Bash-like shell, installed the package Binutils, and using the gnu as assembler and ld linker to compile a short assembly program to open and read a small test disk file in the same path as my source. I am unable to open the file. If I examine the handle created by the open syscall the result is a negative number which is not right. I am not sure about register arguments for the svc call.

Here is my source file (rec1.s) written using nano, compiled using 'as -o rec1.o rec1.s', linked using ld -s -o rec1 rec1.o' and executed using './rec1'

```
.data
title: .ascii "Test disk open for aarch64\n"
filename: .ascii "test.txt"   // existing short text file
path: .ascii "../gas/"      // path where the file resides
err0: .ascii "Zero error\n"
errneg: .ascii "Negative error\n"

.bss
buffer: .space 100

.text
.global _start
_start:
  // title of program 
  mov x0,#1
  ldr x1,=title
  mov x2,#17
  mov w8,#64
  svc 0

  // open disk file 
  ldr x0,=path
  ldr x1,=filename
  mov x2,#0    // flag ?
  mov x3,#0666  // mode ?
  mov w8,#56
  svc 0             // x0 should have handle at this stage
  
  // check for valid handle
  cmp x0,#0    // branch if handle is zero
  beq error0
  blt errorneg
  mov x19,x0   // store handle in x19
  
  // read disk file 
  mov x0,x19
  ldr x1,=buffer
  mov x2,#10
  mov w8,#63
  svc 0

  // display buffer 
  mov x0,#1
  ldr x1,=buffer
  mov x2,#10
  mov w8,#64
  svc 0
  
  // close the file
  mov x0,19
  mov w8,#57
  svc 0
  b exit
  
  exit:
  mov x0,#0
  mov w8,#93
  svc 0
  
  error0:
  mov x0,#1
  ldr x1,=err0
  mov x2,#11
  mov w8,#64
  svc 0
  b exit
  
  errorneg:
  mov x0,#1
  ldr x1,=errneg
  mov x2,#15
  mov w8,#64
  svc 0
  b exit
```

Comment: Shouldn't `filename` and `path` use `.asciz` instead of `.ascii`?

Comment: Hi Siguza. Thank you for providing a possible solution. I tried to use ,asciz as you said for the filename and path but the return handle in x0 still comes back as a negative. My understanding is that ,.asciz appends a zero termination at the end but .ascii does not.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `openat` is not a string, but instead a file descriptor (returned by a previous call to `openat`) or the value `AT_FDCWD` (-100 in Linux) to use the current directory.

The 4th argument is only used when creating files, so it can be omitted.

As Siguva points out the string passed to `openat` should be null-terminated.

```
filename: .asciz "../gas/test.txt"
```

```
  // open disk file 
  mov x0,#-100  // AT_FDCWD
  ldr x1,=filename
  mov x2,#0     // O_RDONLY
  mov w8,#56    // openat
  svc 0
```